# Is there any way to do example based programming?

Tags: functional-programming, language-agnostic, scheme, lisp, code-generation

Is it possible to automatically generate a program/function by writing a certain amount of examples which show the before and after? How many examples would be needed to insure correctness and lack of holes? What is the name of doing such an automatic process?

Comment: What do the guys that closed this reccomend to change for the question not to be too broad? Show some examples? Which place on the internet would you reccomend for such "loose" questions?

Comment: "Example-based programming" is also known as ["programming by example"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_by_example) or "[programming by demonstration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_by_demonstration)."

Answer (score 2):

It's called program synthesis or perhaps guessing. Your question reminds me of the [2013 ICFP programming contest](http://icfpc2013.cloudapp.net/) where you were supposed to guess programs and all you had was the output for your chosen test input in a **very** simple functional language.

So imagine you wanted to make the identity function:

```scm
(define-by-example identity
  (0 -> 0)
  (1 -> 1))
```

There is something missing? What if I told you to make a function that returns it's own value for 0 and 1 only? How would you make that different than the above example? What if it's a non linear transformation. Eg. how many examples does it take to get a polynomial correct?

I guess we're back to something like this:

```scm
(define-by-example fib
  (0 -> 0)
  (1 -> 1)
  (n -> (+ (fib (- n 1)) (fib (- n 2)))))
```

But many languages has exactly this. Even Schemes dirty cousin Racket has this:

```scm
#!racket
(define (fib n)
  (match n
    [0 0]
    [1 1]
    [n (+ (fib (- n 1)) (fib (- n 2)))]))
```

This is the Hello World of Haskell so we better write that next :-)

```hs
-- haskell
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
```

Now there are smart people out there that tries to find the best method of transferring the idea down to a syntax that is clear for the computer and us. I'm sure the essence of "by example" is good but it needs to be a way of explaining the corrolations too and I cannot think of a better way to do that than maths or code where maths don't apply.

Answer (score 2):

This is a subdomain of *machine learning* called *supervised learning*. The most popular method to solve these problems is by using neural networks. Another method is genetic programming.

In the general case it is not possible to guarantee correctness, no matter how large the training set (number of examples) is. But in a typical application this is not required. The training is considered successfull if a high enough percentage os the results is correct.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to automatically generate a program/function by writing a certain amount of examples which show the before and after?

I'd say *yes, but ...*

... it's not exactly that easy, and certainly not that generally applicable. There are basically two "approaches" that I know of:

### a) Try to generate a program

Just pack together program code (most probably instructions from some instruction set) until you get the desired results. This can be done with brute force, but it's hardly possible to synthesize non-trivial functions, yet alone complete programs, or probably with techniques from your favorite artificial intelligence tool set, like hill climbing, simulated annealing, genetic programming and the whole rest.

The only reference that I know of is the ["Superoptimizer" by Henry Massalin](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs343/resources/superoptimizer.pdf), which tries to generate a function that computes the same as a given function, just with fewer instructions.

It's probably better to use some higher level representation of "computation" than assembler instructions (probably the Lisp AST?), but that's just my guess.

### b) Write a meta program that "somehow" learns to behave like the desired program

This is actually very common nowadays in the form of neural networks, e.g. for image or voice recognition. Here you don't try to get a program that does what you want (e.g. "recognize birds in arbitrary images") but rather write a general program that is capable of learning to "behave differently" and train that in order to behave as you want.

Note that there's a lot of effort going into understanding what these meta programs actually do after they learned their intended function. Just taking [the first relevant result](http://yosinski.com/deepvis) from [a Google search](https://www.google.de/search?q=understanding%20what%20a%20neural%20network%20does) is already an interesting read.